# Calculating the value of complex integral around the unit circle.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Hi guys I am computing a complex integral and would just like some feed back if my work seems correct.

The question
Let $\gamma$ be the circle $|z| = 1$. Then compute $\int_\gamma Log(z)$. Where $Log(z)$ is the principal log.

My approach is direct I parametrize the curve and compute $\int_a ^b f(z(t))z'(t)dt$.

Thus  Let $z(t)=e^{i\theta}$ where $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$. As such we can compute $z'(t)=ie^{i\theta}$.

$$ \int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} Log(e^{i \theta})ie^{i \theta}d\theta  = -\int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} \theta e^{i\theta} d\theta
$$
Where we use integration by parts $u= \theta \Rightarrow du=d\theta$ and $dv= e^{i\theta} d\theta \Rightarrow v= -ie^{i \theta}$.

$-\int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} \theta e^{i\theta} d\theta=\large [i \theta e^{i\theta} -e^{i\theta} \large ]_{-\pi} ^{\pi} =\pi i +2$

I would really appreciate it if people comment, also if people have a suggestions on how to calculate this in a better way I am curious.

Comment: What does it mean by principal Log?

Comment: principal value Log z is the logarithm whose imaginary part lies in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: note that $\log$ is discontinous at the unit circle, which means that your integration contour needs to be modified

Comment: But that would be true if I made it from $0$ to$2\pi$. However shouldn't the one I set up avoid the discontinuity?

Comment: Check your integration-by-parts computation -- I think you should be getting $-2 \pi i.$